# c# and XML Deserialization : what about substitutiongroups used for handling globalization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have the following schema:

```
<xs:element name="Company" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="Companhia" substitutionGroup="Company"/>
<xs:element name="Société" substitutionGroup="Company"/>

<xs:complexType name="User">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="Company" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This allows me to successfully validate the following XML Fragments:

```
<User>
  <Company>In English</Company>
</User>
```

and

```
<User>
  <Société>In French</Société>
</User>
```

I'm afraid that the c# class generated by xsd and the corresponding XMLSerializer would work only with the first XML fragment.

In my opinion, I have 2 options:

1. Use XSLT to process the XML file before deserialization in order to promote element name to english ones.
2. Write custom deserialization code.

What do you think ?
Samples would be much appreciated.
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using the following structure for serialization/deserialization:

```
<User>
    <Company language="en">In English</Company>
</User>
```

and

```
<User>
    <Company language="fr">In French</Company>
</User>
```

If your original XML doesn't conform to some fixed structure like this you could use XSLT to transform it.

Comment: In the context of .NET deserialization, the goal is to have only one property in the class that receives the value whatever the element name used in the XML file. In that context, using XSL before deserializing would mean replacing substitution names with the main name that maps to the property.